# Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this error when I activated one plugin. I'm not a professional programmer, but I have some php experience. Help me please. The error is in the `if ( in_array('template-widget', $widgets)) {` line.

```
function ActionWpPrintScripts() {
    global $post;

    // Check to see if widget is present on page
    $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(false);
    $widget_loaded = false;

    if ( is_array($sidebars_widgets) ) {
        foreach ( $sidebars_widgets as $sidebar => $widgets ) {
            if ( in_array('template-widget', $widgets)) {
                $widget_loaded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure that $widgets is an array ^^

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$widgets` and make sure it is an array

Comment: @JohnKugelman this question does _use_ wordpress, but that is not what the issue is about...

Comment: It's a question about a wordpress plugin and involves the `wp_get_sidebars_widgets` function. The [tag:wordpress] and [tag:wordpress-plugin] tags seem appropriate to me.

Comment: what are the values of `$widgets`

Answer (score 1):

The function `wp_get_sidebars_widgets` is not supposed to be called by plugins, only used internally. The documentation also states that

> Upgraded list of widgets to version 3 array format when called **from the admin**.

So that might be the reason why it does not work in the context you are calling it.
My suggestion is to try another approach for whatever you are trying to accomplish.